# Retrieve and output to text files all procedure definitions from Snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a large list of procedures across several schemas in one of our databases, and we need to create a local copy of each one. Is there a function that can cycle through a database, either at database or schema level, to identify the definitions of each of the procedures and output that into a text file?

I have used

`select get_ddl('procedure', 'procedurename()');`

to return the definition of a single procedure, but ideally would need it to cycle through all the procedures and save the outputs into a text file locally. I assume snowsql might come into it, could that do it? Has anyone got any documentation or tips on where to begin to be able to do something like this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL I.e. query for the SPs and then loop through the result set dynamically creating each get_ddl statement before executing it

Comment: Thanks @NickW - you mention executing, I dont want to run the stored procedures, instead export their definitions into a text file (one definition per file). I assume that would need something further than just SQL?

Comment: I meant executing the get_ddl statements, not the actual SP. If you want to copy the result of each one into a file then you’d also need a COPY INTO command in your script

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a starter for how to write the SQL script. It returns all the DDL in one go so obviously you would need to change it to execute a COPY INTO for each SP.

You may also need to adjust it depending on what SPs you have, what access you have to them etc. For example, in the environment I was testing this in I's previously built an app and it had obviously generated an SP in the CORE schema which you can't run a GET_DDL against - and so this code was erroring until I filtered out that record.

```
DECLARE
  RES1 RESULTSET default (show PROCEDURES IN ACCOUNT);
  CUR1 CURSOR FOR RES1;
  DB_NAME TEXT DEFAULT '';
  SCHEMA_NAME TEXT DEFAULT '';
  PROC_NAME TEXT DEFAULT '';
  PROC_NAME_CLEAN TEXT DEFAULT '';
  PROC_NAME_QUAL TEXT DEFAULT '';
  SQL_STMT TEXT DEFAULT '';
  SQL_STMT_UNION TEXT DEFAULT '';
  SQL_STMT_RESULT RESULTSET;

BEGIN
  FOR RECORD IN CUR1 DO 
    IF (RECORD."is_builtin" = 'N' AND RECORD."schema_name" <> 'CORE') THEN
      DB_NAME := RECORD."catalog_name";
      SCHEMA_NAME := RECORD."schema_name";
      PROC_NAME := RECORD."arguments";
      PROC_NAME_CLEAN := substr(PROC_NAME,1,position(') RETURN ', PROC_NAME));
      PROC_NAME_QUAL := DB_NAME||'.'||SCHEMA_NAME||'.'||PROC_NAME_CLEAN;
      SQL_STMT := 'SELECT GET_DDL(\'PROCEDURE\', \''||PROC_NAME_QUAL||'\',TRUE)';

      IF (SQL_STMT_UNION = '' ) THEN
        SQL_STMT_UNION := SQL_STMT;
      ELSE
        SQL_STMT_UNION := SQL_STMT_UNION||' UNION '||SQL_STMT;
      END IF;
    END IF;
    
  END FOR;

  SQL_STMT_RESULT := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQL_STMT_UNION);
  RETURN TABLE(SQL_STMT_RESULT);

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN statement_error THEN
    RETURN 'ERROR: '||:SQL_STMT;
  
  WHEN OTHER THEN
    RETURN OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('Error type', 'Other error',
                            'SQLCODE', sqlcode,
                            'SQLERRM', sqlerrm,
                            'SQLSTATE', sqlstate);
  

END;
```